# How to order a list by property and group the elements in HTML Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

Maybe the question is hard to explain all but here is the problem I'm facing, I have a list of properties of a model

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int PropertyID {get;set;}
    public DateTime Datefield {get;set}
    public string OtherProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Then I fill the list with some values:

```
List<ViewModel> listOfValues = new List<ViewModel>();
listOfValues.Add(new ViewModel{
    PropertyID = 1,
    Datefield = new DateTime(2010, 5,25, 12,00,00),
    OtherProperty = "Name1"
});
```

Imagine the Datefield has this values:

```
0: 25/05/2010 12:00:00
1: 25/05/2010 12:00:00
2: 26/05/2010 13:00:00
3: 26/05/2010 13:00:00
4: 26/05/2010 14:00:00
5: 27/05/2010 12:00:00
```

After that I order the list with simple `listOfElements.OrderBy(o => o.Datefield).ThenBy(o => o.Datefield.Hour);` to order the list first by date, and after the date the hour most recent.

Everything works fine but then one requirement is to "group" the elements by date and hour, but not with a `GroupBy` of LINQ, but with RAZOR in this way:

```
    <div>
        @Model.listOfElements[i].Datefield //0: 25/05/2010 12:00:00
        @Model.listOfElements[i].Datefield //1: 25/05/2010 12:00:00
    </div>

    <div>
        @Model.listOfElements[i].Datefield //2: 26/05/2010 13:00:00
        @Model.listOfElements[i].Datefield //3: 26/05/2010 13:00:00
    </div>

    <div>
        @Model.listOfElements[i].Datefield //4: 26/05/2010 14:00:00
    </div>

    <div>
        @Model.listOfElements[i].Datefield //5: 27/05/2010 12:00:00
    </div>
```

I wanted to group them by date and hour in the html so the ones that matches are, for example, in a div so I can give them style that they are kind of a group. I tried with some ugly razor-html syntax but I don't think it's the best way.

Hope the question is understandable.

Comment: It is understandable - you need to get the ["day"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - ["month"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month(v=vs.110).aspx) as separate properties. You can do this on the client side (razor/js/jq,etc) but why not just make  two new properties in your viewmodel?

Comment: But how do I compare the index 0 againts index 1 for example, and determine that they are the same date and hour. What I imagine was comparing the index 0 and then the current index + 1 so I could compare the next one, and the final index validate that it's not out of range

Comment: Its hard to give you succinct advice because we dont know how you're filling your `List<ViewModel>`...  I think  StuartLC's is a good one, but why is the indexing of your list important?

Comment: The indexing is not important, is just to show that the element is the one I put in the example to clarity the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming as per your code that `Model.listOfElements` contains the `IEnumerable<ViewModel>` given, what you can do is use Linq to Group the dates, and then each grouping will itself contain a list of items in that date group. In order to obtain the Date+Hour only grouping, use an anonymous projection in the Grouping to just consider the Date and Hour in the Grouping

```
@foreach (var grp in Model.listOfElements 
    .OrderBy(m => m.PropertyID)
    .GroupBy(m => string.Format("{0:yyyyMMddHH}", m.Datefield)))
{
    <div>
        @foreach (var itm in grp)
        {
            <p>@itm.PropertyID - @itm.Datefield</p>
        }
    </div>
}
```

The pre-ordering on `PropertyID` will pull through to the Groupings to give the order you've listed. I've added the `PropertyId` to the output just for demonstration - you can remove it once the ordering is confirmed.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the Date + Hour grouping requirement, first up. Much the same approach, just use a projection which discards the minutes + seconds when doing the grouping.

Comment: Yes it's working fine with the test I run! only I have a question, I couldn't "convert" from `@foreach(var itm in grp)` to @for(int i = 0; i < grp.Count; i++) because that way I could send the list via POST, I don´t know if that's possible

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you also want to build some `<inputs>` so that the form can be posted back, and you want them keyed on the original propertyid?

Comment: Yes, I would like to send the inputs to be posted back, the propertyID, Datefield and Selected (bool) as a checkbox, so in the controller I could receive the List<ViewModel> as the user send it, because in the grouping the original list does not exist and the model is not binded

Comment: Well the original question was order the elements by hour, I forgot to mention that I want to send the model back to the controller, but your answer solved the question. Thanks for your help